# Are key evolving signatures (or forward secure signatures) that secure?

Tags: signature, forward-secrecy

Reading this paper [Forward-Secure Digital Signature Scheme](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/%7Emihir/papers/fsig.pdf) I discovered the notion of key evolving signatures. The intuition behind these signatures is clear: one uses different private keys to generate keys in different periods of time, while maintaining the same public key.

The paper stresses that whenever a secret key is used it has to be deleted from memory (either physical or computational), to achieve forward security. What happens if not? What if I decide to sell my past secret keys to an adversary before erasing them?

These signatures have been recently used in blockchains like [AlgoRand](https://www.algorand.com/) to ensure that even if an adversary is able to discover the secret key in period $i$, he is not able to discover secret keys from previous periods (hence, not being able to rewrite the history of the chain). Anyways, what happens if users decide to sell past keys to this adversary? He would be able to rewrite the history as if it would have been used a standard signature scheme.

Clearly, this scheme has a better security; but it is not still secure enough in worst cases.

Comment: Why are users keeping then selling their used secret keys, even hypothetically?  And in a blockchain the attacker can do little unless they have all the used secret keys?

Comment: Well, they keep selling them because they are able to earn more. Agree on the 2nd one

Comment: If it's a blockchain the keys will be worth little (perhaps nothing) alone, and all of them will be worth something. And you have a mining process to break (presumably). It doesn't really seem a legitimate threat as it requires everyone becoming disinvested, which itself breaks a cryptocurrency.  It's also difficult to imagine any protocol maintaining  full security when users are actively trying to break it.

Comment: @ModalNest Yeah, in practise it looks like there have to be perfect circumstances for it to happen. But, theoretically, which is the difference between using a standard signature scheme or a key evolving signature (KES)? The same attack could be executed in both scenarios. Using KES just makes it less "probable" that the attack happens, but sill I don't see the key point on using KES (apart from the fact that their are more computationally costly).

Comment: I suppose the short answer would be it isn't designed for this sort of "attack". The paper is you linked is essentially [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy#Example) if I'm reading it right (except its for signatures).  The purpose is to make sure that if the key is compromised, previous messages cannot be decrypted (or signed). Clearly the point of KES isn't to protect against this impossible attack.  You could equally ask what the point of encryption/signing is in general, because it doesn't protect against the attack that you give away all your keys.